Artefact in power spectrum for raw EEG data
I have recently started working with EEG data. Looking at the power spectrum for raw data, I see a weird artifact at very low frequencies.

I wonder if this is something I should be worried about or should I just filter it out with a high pass filter?
Please see two diagnostic plots:



take the mean out and see what you get!

You might also have a low frequency trend. There are many ways to detrend data, but I suggest you take it one step at a time

This might be drift. If it is, a low frequency highpass filter might help. See https://mne.tools/stable/auto_tutorials/preprocessing/30_filtering_resampling.html#slow-drifts for more info on drift
